# Get SQL UserName that modified a table in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the sql username that modified a table? I have this query but I didn't find this info, it is probably another table?

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'MyDb')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('dbo.mytable')
```

Comment: Do you mean changed the table structure or changed data within a table?

Comment: Try: http://serverfault.com/questions/258111/finding-out-who-has-modified-a-stored-procedure-on-sql-server

Comment: who changed data within a table

Comment: If you don't have logging in place you don't. The default trace does not track dml statements.

Comment: @Sean Lange: could you explain me that logging in place? what do you mean exactly? thanks

Comment: You would need to have some sort of logging that you build. A simple example, yet one that is extremely common is like the answer posted below by @jhilden. If you need more details you will have to track it yourself and store that information in another table. This could be done via triggers or the procedures that perform your dml.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way within the SQL Server sys tables to get who modified a record for a table.

As a best practice you should always have the following columns on tables that users can edit:

- CreatedBy
- CreationDate
- LastModifiedBy
- LastModifiedDate